# Is there an algebraic way to solve an equation with linear and trigonometric terms

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

given an equation such as

$3x + 2\sin(x) = 0$

Is there an algebraic way to solve this?

Comment: Generally not, as $\sin x$ is transcendental when $x$ is algebraic.

Comment: That makes alot of sense. thanks for the quick answer

Comment: ${{{{\rm No.}}}}$

Comment: What is the general form of the equation you want to solve, is it $ax + b \sin x = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course!

$0$ is a root.

Now, prove that $\sin{x}>-\frac{3x}{2}$ for $x>0$ and $\sin{x}<-\frac{3x}{2}$ for $x<0$.

For example, for $0<x<\pi$ we obtain:
$$\sin{x}>0>-\frac{3x}{2}$$